# Datatype for holding number of votes

Tags: database, vote

Which datatype in a database can I use for holding number of votes, as the like-button on Facebook?
I’m not looking for a rating system, which holds values between 1 and 5 for instance. I’m looking for a datatype which lets the user vote up or down, or where the user only can vote up.

Comment: How about a number??? I don't understand the question, it seems kinda obvious... ("..for holding number of votes")

Comment: to store up/down vote; CHAR(1) is enough; if it counter then number.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use it for math, like adding up the votes at some point, use int (probably should anyway, because at some point you probably will want to do some addition, or other math ops).  Otherwise, use CHAR.